# How to catch Ctrl + Alt + RShftKey

Tags: vb.net

For some time I'm trying to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift Key</kbd> under common VBNET key handler.
Here are my tests:

```
    If e.Control And e.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + ALT + SPACE") ' This work
    End If

    If e.Control And e.Shift And e.KeyCode = Keys.F10 Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + SHIFT + F10") ' This work
    End If

    If e.Control And e.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.ShiftKey Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + ALT + SHIFT") ' This work
    End If

    If e.Alt And e.Shift And e.KeyCode = Keys.LWin Then
        MsgBox("ALT + SHIFT + LEFT WINDOWS") ' This work
    End If

    If e.Control And e.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.RShiftKey Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + ALT + RIGHT SHIFT") ' This don't work
    End If
```

Windows 7, WinForms, VB2008, NET framework 2.0

Why I can't catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift Key</kbd> in described situation?
Or, how do I catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift Key</kbd> combination?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to detect difference between Shifts using standard VB.NET approach.
You will have to hook into Windows API for that:

```
 <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(vKey As Keys) As Short
    End Function

    Private Sub Form2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

        If e.Control And e.Alt And e.Shift Then

            If Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LShiftKey)) Then
                MsgBox("CTRL + ALT + LEFT SHIFT")
            ElseIf Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey)) Then
                MsgBox("CTRL + ALT + RIGHT SHIFT")
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Very interesting. Why then RShiftKey and LShiftKey are enumerated under Keys constants? Did same apply to LControlKey and RControlKey? What else don't work as expected?

Comment: Updated my answer to workable solution - this is where you use those enumerated codes

Comment: It has a problem.  Press an arbitrary other key after holding the three keys down and see that it triggers the message box.

Comment: You mean after holding ctrl+alt+shift and the message is displayed?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is tricky since these are all modifier keys and the user could press them in any order.  You'll need to do some filtering to ensure that a 4th key press doesn't again produce a match, a problem with the accepted answer.   And the right-shift key is difficult, it is reported as Keys.Shift when pressed.  That requires pinvoke to check if the key is down.

This worked well:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If Control.ModifierKeys = (Keys.Control Or Keys.Alt Or Keys.Shift) Then
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.ControlKey Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Menu Or e.KeyCode = Keys.ShiftKey Then
            If GetKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey) < 0 And GetKeyState(Keys.LShiftKey) >= 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("yada")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal key As Keys) As Short
```

This works by first verifying that all three modifier keys are down.  Then it checks that the last key was pressed was *one* of the three keys, the filtering that ensures you don't get too many matches.  Finally it checks if the right-shift key is down and it didn't get there by pressing the left-shift as well.

Comment: Thanks Hans, your example also work as expected but Yuri responses first.

Comment: It is not the same answer.

Comment: Of course not but both based on user32.dll and well known GetKeyState. Do you think that Yuri's solution is not good enough? By tests it behaves well.

Comment: I don't know if I understand well but your example also work if I press RShift then Control then Alt, but that is OK I think...

Comment: It better be, you can't count on the user picking the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```
    If e.Control And e.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.ShiftKey Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + ALT + SHIFT") ' This work
        Debug.Print("CTRL + ALT + SHIFT" & GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ShiftKey) & GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey)) 
    End If

    If e.Control And e.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.RShiftKey Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + ALT + RIGHT SHIFT") ' This don't work
        Debug.Print("CTRL + ALT + RIGHT SHIFT " & GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ShiftKey) & GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey))
    End If
```

You will see that the value for Keys.ShiftKey is the same for left and right. The test for Keys.RShiftKey changes. The DECLARE from above is required for the API call.

Comment: Interesting experiment which gives "workable this": If e.Control And e.Alt And GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey) Then...